# How do I fix my if statement not being recognized as true

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, scanf

I wrote my program that is supposed to check if someone is single, married (either separated or joint) and if they were the head of the house hold in order to calculate the taxes they have to pay. For some reason when i type y for the first scanf the next if statement gets skipped. Please help! Here is my whole code. I know it is not the most optimized and they I could clean it up but I'm just trying to figure out what is wrong with it first.

```
    void question3 (void)
    {
    char single, head, joint;
    int income = 0;
    double tax = 0;

    printf("What is your total income?");
    scanf("%d", &income);

    printf ("Are you single? (y/n) \n");
    scanf (" %c", &single);

    if (single == 'y')
    {
        if (income == 17850)
        {
            tax = income * .15;
        }
        else if (income >= 17850)
        {
            tax = ((.15 * 17850) + (.28 * (income - 17850)));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (single != 'y')
        {
        printf("Are you the head of the house hold? y or n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &head);
        }
    }

    if (head == 'y')
    {
        if (income == 23900)
        {
         tax = income * .15;
        }
        else if (income >= 23900)
        {
         tax = ((.15 * 23900) + (.28 * (income - 23900)));
        }
    }
    else if (head != 'y')
    {
        printf("Do you have a joint marriage\n");
        scanf(" %c", &joint);
    }

    if (joint == 'y')
    {
        if (income == 29750)
        {
         tax = income * .15;
        }
        else if (income >= 29750)
        {
        tax = ((.15 * 29750) + (.28 * (income - 29750)));
        }
    }
    else if (joint != 'y')
    {
        if(income == 14875)
        {
         tax = income * .15;
        }
        else if (income >= 14875)
        {
         tax = ((.15 * 14875) + (.28 * (income - 14875)));
        }

    }

    printf("You owe %f dollars in taxes.", tax);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't the first call to `scanf` asking for income?  Also, your if statements should probably be checking if income is less than an amount, rather than exactly equal to it.

Comment: There's no reason for your `else if (blah != 'y')` when a simple `else` will do. Also, what happens if the `income` is less than your magic numbers (like `17850`)?  You should have `if <` and an `else`. Walk through your logic by hand and think about what happens at each value.

Comment: Also the code for Joint and the last else if works fine and gives out the correct results (7332.5 and 9266.5 respectively) but when I type y for single it goes on to ask me the household question and if I say y to that then it gives me the answer to the last else if. I just cant figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You should start with `char head = 'y';` Otherwise, when `single` is `'y'` there's no value assigned to `head`. BTW, the compiler should be warning you about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use functions to break it up, so that for every true expression, it calls a function. In each of the functions you ask for the income and then give result. After the result is printed it calls question3 to repeat the cycle.

For every false  expression you give another choice, that also either calls a function or gives another choice.

```
char single, head, joint;
int income = 0;
double tax = 0;

void Single();
void Head();
void Joint();

void question3(void)
{
    printf("Are you single? (y/n) \n");
    scanf(" %c", &single);

    if (single == 'y')
    {
        Single();
    }
    else if (single == 'n')
    {
        printf("Are you the head of the house hold? y or n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &head);

        if (head == 'y')
        {
            Head();
        }
        else if (head == 'n')
        {
            printf("Do you have a joint marriage\n");
            scanf(" %c", &joint);

            if (joint == 'y')
            {
                Joint();
            }
            else if(joint == 'n')
            {
               question3();
            }
        }
    }
}

void Single()
{
    printf("What is your total income?");
    scanf("%d", &income);

    if (income == 17850)
    {
        tax = income * .15;
    }
    else if (income >= 17850)
    {
        tax = ((.15 * 17850) + (.28 * (income - 17850)));
    }

    printf("You owe %f dollars in taxes.\n\n", tax);

    question3();

    return 0;
}

void Head()
{
    printf("What is your total income?");
    scanf("%d", &income);

    if (income == 23900)
    {
        tax = income * .15;
    }
    else if (income >= 23900)
    {
        tax = ((.15 * 23900) + (.28 * (income - 23900)));
    }

    printf("You owe %f dollars in taxes.\n\n", tax);

    question3();

    return 0;
}

void Joint()
{
    printf("What is your total income?");
    scanf("%d", &income);

    if (income == 29750)
    {
        tax = income * .15;
    }
    else if (income >= 29750)
    {
        tax = ((.15 * 29750) + (.28 * (income - 29750)));
    }

    printf("You owe %f dollars in taxes.\n", tax);

    question3();

    return 0;
}

void main()
{
   question3();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For a single char, you should use [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getc) rather than `scanf`:

```
single = getchar();
```

If you stick with `scanf`:

- You should remove the space (hence `scanf("%c", &single)`).
- You should probably test the return of `scanf`: it returns the number of arg it could parse (in your case, it should be 1 if ok, 0 otherwise).

On another note, this is useless:

```
if (single == 'y') {
  ...
} else if (single != 'y') {
  ...
}
```

If you don't care about single being absolutely equals to y or n, then you should simply write those if like that:

```
if (single == 'y') {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not my DV but the space in `” %c”` is correct and crucial.

Comment: It's been a long time I've coded in C. But I did not remember using " %c" (or I would use getchar()).

Comment: I'm not sure whether it was widespread knowledge when you were using C.  It's something I picked up in the last decade and a bit — since joining SO, but quite a long time ago — but it deals with the newline left behind by the previous input (the income).  I mostly avoid `scanf()` and `fscanf()` even now; I use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` or something similar in preference.